# codeception symfony2 unit test throws a fatal error

Tags: symfony, phpunit

using the classical phpunit style I generate:test with the symfony2 helper. 
I can get the service and I can assert it ok.

// tests
    public function testGetServiceUrl() {
        $ecservice = $this->getModule('Symfony2')->grabServiceFromContainer("ecservice");

```
    $this->assertEquals("https://ecoconnect2.niwa.co.nz/services", $ecservice->getServiceUrl());
    $this->assertEquals("xxx", $ecservice->getServiceUrl());

}
```

However in the second case where the assertion fails I get an exception:

```
    Trying to test get service url (demoTest::testGetServiceUrl) - Failed
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getResponse() on a non-object in /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Util/Framework.php on line 30
    PHP Stack trace:
    PHP   1. {main}() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:0
    PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept:38
    PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:106
    PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:193
    PHP   5. Codeception\Command\Run->execute() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:240
    PHP   6. Codeception\Codecept->runSuite() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php:74
    PHP   7. Codeception\SuiteManager->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php:110
    PHP   8. Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php:132
    PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Runner.php:107
    PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
    PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
    PHP  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:776
    PHP  13. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->addFailure() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:698
    PHP  14. Codeception\PHPUnit\Listener->addFailure() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:307
    PHP  15. Codeception\PHPUnit\Listener->fire() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Listener.php:24
    PHP  16. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/PHPUnit/Listener.php:66
    PHP  17. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:53
    PHP  18. call_user_func() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:164
    PHP  19. Codeception\Subscriber\Module->failed() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php:164
    PHP  20. Codeception\Util\Framework->_failed() /Users/watkinsav/workspace/cd/ecoconnect_web/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Subscriber/Module.php:47
```

This is because the _failed() function in the     Framework.php tries to call client-getResponse().  And we don't have a response class instantiated.

```
public function _failed(\Codeception\TestCase $test, $fail)
 {
     if (!$this->client->getResponse()) return;
     file_put_contents(\Codeception\Configuration::logDir() . basename($test->getFileName()) . '.page.debug.html',  $this->client->getResponse()->getContent());
 }
```

In the example blog post here: http://codeception.com/02-12-2013/testing-symfony2.html There are some extra lines - but they do not fix the problem.

Thanks again Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like this function expected to get null from getResponse.

```
if (!$this->client->getResponse()) return;
```

This line should have blocked the screenshot call if no response is available.
However it didn't. Looks like an issue. Which Symfony version do you use?

Comment: here are my composer settings: 
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "v1.1.0-alpha4",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",